# How can I lock user keyboard and mouse using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript file which is uninstall amd install manager.

I want to lock user mouse and keyboard for seconds during this uninstall operation or block input from mouse and keyboard for seconds

Is it possible to lock user keyboard and mouse using Vbscript?
or are there any possbilities? How can i do this
Give me someadvices. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you google for your question? A lot of answers... E.g. AutoIt

Comment: Yes I saw Autoit etc but i dont kw how to use it with vbscript. But i dont want to use autoit. is it possible to use only with vbscript

Comment: Are you trying to prevent users clicking Cancel on those un/install? Most installers support passive or quiet switches.

Comment: YES im prevent users to clicking cancel button. I know that but seems amd catalyst install manager does not have quiet etc

Answer (score 0):

You could start internet explorer in theater mode (fullscreen without controls) and load a small html description what's happening at this moment.
Like:
"Please wait while catalyst is installing"

Or use the BlockInput function from User32.dll

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
and http://www.sqaforums.com/showthreaded.php?Number=304927

Comment: Yeah i used block input and its worked but when I run this with cata uninstall vbs.It is also stopping my uninstallation 2

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't understand what you mean.  When you run your uninstallation script for catalyst control center it would stop the installation by using `BlockInput(true)`?

Comment: Would you please post your script code?
I think we become a better imagination of what you are doing exactly and what you are trying. If you are using `SendKeys` Method, the inputs will be blocked with `BlockInput`.   
And take a look at [http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/69807-faq-installing-ati-ccc-silently/](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/69807-faq-installing-ati-ccc-silently/)

Comment: Yes I am Using SendKeys so how can i prevent that are there any way?

Comment: Any methods to prevent user input would block your `SendKeys()` calls. Best way is to install ccc manually without the catalyst install manager. Did you looked at the link?

Comment: CCC is the ATI Catalyst Control Center.

Comment: You should rethink your whole installation concept. if you are using things like `SendKeys()` it's impossible with VBScript to send key or mouse inputs.