# How to call BlockInput in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I have found on this [site](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=304924&page=&fpart=&vc=1) code for VBS to block user input. To simplify, code is:

```
Sub StopKeyMouse()
    Set Def_DLL = DLL.DefineDLL("USER32")
    Def_Proc = Def_DLL.DefineProc("BlockInput", vt_b1, vt_b1) 
    Set Lib = DLL.Load("USER32.DLL", "USER32")
    Lib.BlockInput(True)
End Sub

Sub ResumeKeyMouse()
  Set Def_DLL = DLL.DefineDLL("USER32")
  Def_Proc = Def_DLL.DefineProc("BlockInput", vt_b1, vt_b1) 
  Set Lib = DLL.Load("USER32.DLL", "USER32")
  Lib.BlockInput(False)
End Sub

Sub Test()
    StopKeyMouse()

    WScript.Sleep 1000
    
    ResumeKeyMouse()
End Sub

Test()
```

When I run it, I get the error `Object required: 'DLL'`. Since the post is from 2004, I assume that VBS interaction with User32.dll has been changed.

I am missing a line with `CreateObject`, something like `Set DLL = CreateObject("User32.dll")`.

Does anybody know what is correct code for script to work?

I have also found that it was possible to use

```
Set oAutoIt = CreateObject("AutoItX.Control")   
oAutoIt.BlockInput "on"
```

But this is obsolete.

Is it possible to call [BlockInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN) from VBS?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: That code is specific to [TestComplete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/), the object `DLL` is not something available in vanilla VBScript. If you want to make Windows API calls in VBScript you would have to build a COM DLL that can be used via `CreateObject()` in VBScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I lock user keyboard and mouse using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778334/how-can-i-lock-user-keyboard-and-mouse-using-vbscript)

Comment: I have seen that post. Example code is from the answer to that post. My code is just simplified. Thank you.

Comment: Already tried to explain the code you have posted is specific to [Smartbear TestComplete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/). The [`DLL` object](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/program-objects/dll/index.html) is a COM DLL that TestComplete initialises it has nothing to do with vanilla VBScript so you will not be able to use it in a script outside of TestComplete. That question does contain a bunch of other answers though that explain different approaches. To answer your question, no it is not possible in vanilla VBScript.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that it is for TestComplete, I did not read the first post. Thank you for answer and explanation.